# Rails - Model association seems to be saving, but not loaded during find()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

In one model, I have this:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :turn

  attr_accessor :turn
  attr_accessible :turn

  default_scope :include => :turn

  def Game.new_game
    turn = Turn.create count: 1, phase: 'upkeep', player: 1
    game = Game.create turn: turn
    game
  end
end

class Turn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Later, in a controller, I have this:

```
respond_with Game.find(params[:id])
```

But for some reason, the returned game has a `turn_id` that is `nil` and no associated `turn` object.

Why isn't the association being saved properly, or not returning properly with `find()`?

In my migration, I think I've setup the association correctly:

```
create_table :games do |t|
   t.timestamps
end

def change
 create_table :turns do |t|
   t.string :phase
   t.integer :count

   t.references :game
   t.timestamps
 end
```

end

Comment: If you want a game to have a turn_id, the game has to `belong_to :turn` and the turn in turn would `has_one :game`

But I'm guessing a game should have more than one turn? Shouldn't the game `has_many :turns` and the turn `belongs_to :game`?

Comment: Also how are you setting the turn_id for a game? If the game does not get a reference to a turn it will be nil. You also need to have in the Turn model has_many :games I believe.

Comment: There is a single turn which represents the current turn state information.

Comment: This oddly works with has_many and not has_one. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have got messed up on associations

This is what i Think as per the understanding of scenario.

The associations should be like

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :turn

  #.....
end

class Turn < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  #.....
end
```

and migrations like

```
create_table :games do |t|
  #add some columns
  t.timestamps
end


create_table :turns do |t|
  t.references :game
  #add some columns
  t.timestamps
end
```

now to add new game and turn

```
    game = Game.create 
    turn = game.turn.create  count: 1, phase: 'upkeep', player: 1
```

`game.tun.create` will automatically create a turn record with `game_id = game.id` and other supplied args.

problem with your migration is game is referring turn which instead should be opposite .

Find more on associations here
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: This doesn't work. game.turn.create is undefined, first of all, and game.build_turn yields the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something is inverted.

Since Turn has the belongs_to statement, Turn should contain game_id, and not the other way around.

So you can't access a Game turn_id because the field does not exists. It will be always nil and if ou remove the has_one statement it will raise an exception.